# Bijection between $\{(p, q): p+q=k\}\sqcup X$ and $\{(r, s): r+s=k\}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Fix an element $k\in\mathbb N_0$. What is the relationship between the sets $$\{(p, q)\in \mathbb N_0\times\mathbb N_0: p+q=k\}$$ and $$\{(r, s)\in\mathbb N_0\times \mathbb N_0: r+s=k+1\}. $$ I believe there is a bijection:

$$\{(r, s)\in \mathbb N_0\times \mathbb N_0: r+s=k+1\}\simeq \{(p, q)\in \mathbb N_0\times \mathbb N_0: p+q=k\}\sqcup X$$ for a suitable set $X$. Is that true? What would be that $X$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that there exists a bijection between two sets if and only if they have the same cardinality.
We can count the set (which I refer to as $A$)
$$A = \{(p, q)\in \mathbb N_0\times\mathbb N_0: p+q=k\} = \{(p, k-p) : p\in \mathbb{N}_0,k-p\ge 0\}$$
explicitly. We have
$$A=\{(0,k),(1,k-1),...,(k-1,1),(k,0)\}.$$
Similarly,
$$B = \{(r, s)\in \mathbb N_0\times\mathbb N_0: r+s=k+1\} = \{(r, k+1-r) : r\in \mathbb{N}_0,k + 1-r \ge 0\}$$
and we have
$$B=\{(0,k+1),(1,k),...,(k,1),(k+1,0)\}.$$
Certainly $|A| = k+1$ and $|B|=k+2$. Thus, to achieve a bijection $B \simeq A \sqcup X$, we must have
$$|B| = |A \sqcup X| = |A| +|X|$$
$$k+2 = k+1 +|X| \implies |X| = 1.$$
So, any one point set $X = \{x\}$ would do.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with coordinates $x$ and $y.$ Fixing $k,$ you can plot the graph of $x+y=k.$ You are interested in the set of points which:

- are on this line (that's the bit after the colon in your description of the set),
- have integer coordinates (because $\mathbb{N}_{0}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$),
- lie in the first quadrant, including the axes (because the condition ``$\geq0$'' is what specifies $\mathbb{N}_{0}$ within $\mathbb{Z}$).

Plot your sets for small values of $k$ and see what happens.